# "DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (05 December 2012 - 09:30 AM) at position 17 (-): Unexpected character"

Tags: laravel

```
$start = Carbon::parse($request->date1);
$end = Carbon::parse($request->date2);
$allSchedules = $allSchedules->where('dateTime','<=',$end)->where('dateTime','>=',$start);
```

> "DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (05 December
>   2012 - 09:30 AM) at position 17 (-): Unexpected character"

Comment: Please update your question to include all relevant information. Please read official [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error said, remove the dash (-) from the date you are sending to Carbon construct.

either from the client, or right on the parse method:

```
$start = Carbon::parse(str_replace('-', '', $request->date1));
```